# Id's in array javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a set of id's in my HTML-script. Is there a proper way to put them in an array in javascript to change the the background of all id's("blauw*) at once?

Here's my HTML code:

```
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><a href="#"><img id="blauw1" src="images/lamp_uit.png" width="32" height="63"></a></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><a href="#"><img id="blauw2" src="images/lamp_uit.png" width="32" height="63"></a></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><a href="#"><img id="blauw3" src="images/lamp_uit.png" width="32" height="63"></a></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><a href="#"><img id="blauw4" src="images/lamp_uit.png" width="32" height="63"></a></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><a href="#"><img id="blauw5" src="images/lamp_uit.png" width="32" height="63"></a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><img id="blauw6" src="images/lamp_uit.png" width="32" height="63"></a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><img id="blauw7" src="images/lamp_uit.png" width="32" height="63"></a></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><a href="#"><img id="blauw8" src="images/lamp_uit.png" width="32" height="63"></a></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><a href="#"><img id="blauw9" src="images/lamp_uit.png" width="32" height="63"></a></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><a href="#"><img id="blauw10" src="images/lamp_uit.png" width="32" height="63"></a></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

Comment: Actually I dont know why this question is devoted!!! Its about programming, it has source in it, its clear what the op wants. I never read about any rules that your source has to be professional!. So even if its a bad code its not a matter of devoting. Also not knowing an answere to a question is no matter of devoting! There for ill vote this up!

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) selecting the elements by a [substring](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) of `id` attribute:

```
document.querySelectorAll("img[id^=blauw]");
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apwr86xg/)**</kbd>

e.g.:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll("img[id^=blauw]");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].src = "";
}
```

Notes:

- [`querySelectorAll()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) and [CSS3 selectors](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) has partial support on IE8;
- You should really use *classes* to select a group of elements like `class="blauw"`.

  By adding a class you could get rid of some of those attributes in your tag:

  ```
  .blauw {
      width: 32px 
      height: 63px
  }

  <img class="blauw" src="images/lamp_uit.png" />
  ```

Comment: Can I change the background like this?document.querySelectorAll("img[id^=blauw]").src="images/lamp_blauw.png";

Comment: @Manariba nope. `querySelectorAll` will return a collection of html elements, you have to loop'em all and change each one's background. Check the update.

Comment: Any idea for the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518283/bar-graph-stack-data-on-the-top-of-each-other

Answer (score 1):

Not really. IDs are unique across the document. CSS doesn't allow wilcards in ID selectors, e.g.

```
#blauw* { color: red }
```

is illegal syntax. You'd have to write an insanely wasteful/inneficient:

```
#blauw1, #blauw2, ..., #blauw999999 { color: red }
```

If you want to color them all the same, why not give them a class?

```
.blauw { color: red}

<img id="..." class="blauw" ... />
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: but with js he can do it very well... even doe its wrong to use id in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a class to all those elements, and then use getElementsByClassName to get those elements ref in to JS array.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better using a `blauw` class.

But assuming the last parts of the IDs are consecutive integers starting at 1,

```js
var i = 0, arr = [], el;
while(el = document.getElementById('blauw' + ++i)) arr.push(el);
```