# Bar graph Stack data on the top of each other

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am using [this chart implementation](http://dojo.telerik.com/iQOKE).
 However, it disperse my data rather than stack on the top of each other.

I want to stack my first array on 1970, the second one on 1975. In other words, I would like to have two stacked bar rather than have five. I would like to keep my data array as it is, rather than seperating them into pieces.

```
function createChart() {
  $("#chart").kendoChart({
    title: {
      text: "World population by age group and sex"
    },
    legend: {
      visible: false
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
      type: "column"
    },
    series: [{
      name: "1970",
      stack: true,
      data: [85, 92, 98, 104, 54]
    }, {
      name: "1975",
      stack: true,
      data: [49, 50, 55, 56, 95]
    }],


    seriesColors: ["green", "yellow", "#dc5c71", "#e47f8f", "#eba1ad",
      "#009bd7", "#26aadd", "#4db9e3", "#73c8e9", "#99d7ef"
    ],
    valueAxis: {
      labels: {
        template: "#= kendo.format('{0:N0}', value )#"
      },
      line: {
        visible: false
      }
    },
    categoryAxis: {
      categories: [1970, 1975],
      majorGridLines: {
        visible: false
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      visible: true,
      template: "#= series.stack #s, age #= series.name #"
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(createChart);
$(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/va5pu8tf/)**

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Desired Output:** is similar to as follows

[image]

Comment: Could you post the chart code here? Or put it in a jsfiddle. My corporate network is blocking Telerik Dojo. :(

Comment: Any updates Nicholas. Something similar to http://jsfiddle.net/n9xvof2y/4/ following example, he concatenate arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try arranging your data like this:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
     title: {
        text: "World population by age group and sex"
    },
    theme: "Metro",
    legend: {
        visible: false
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "column"
    },               
    series: [
      {
       name: "item1",
       stack: true,
       data: [85, 49]
     },{
       name: "item2",
       stack: true,
       data: [ 92, 50]
     },{
       name: "item3",
       stack: true,
       data: [98, 55]
     },{
       name: "item4",
       stack: true,
       data: [104, 56]
     },,{
       name: "item5",
       stack: true,
       data: [54,95]
     }, 
    ],
    valueAxis: {
        labels: {
            template: "#= kendo.format('{0:N0}', value )#"
        },
        line: {
            visible: false
        }
    },
    categoryAxis: {
        categories: [1970, 1975],
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: false
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        template: "#= series.name # #= value #"
    }
});
```

**Updated [DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/uRUpu)**

**Updated [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/va5pu8tf/1/)**

Comment: Is there a way to keep array itself, rather than separating them in pieces? Actually that is my main point.

Comment: @mystackoverflow, have a look at http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/grouped-data.  You would need to group by item instead of year to get one series per item with 2 points...

Comment: I would like to have it as follows http://jsfiddle.net/n9xvof2y/3/ He has only one data array and handle it. By the way, I have upvoted your answer,however I have been dealing with this issue for many hours.

Comment: could you give me an example please how to make it?

Comment: I think @ezanker is right, this seems to be the way to go. You need to adjust your dataset so that Kendo can use it.

Comment: @mystackoverflow, for grouping you use one array of objects like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/va5pu8tf/2/. The fiddle you linked last uses highcharts not kendo and it also does not group the way you want...

Comment: Perfect, that is what I have been looking for. You are great! I have marked your answer.

Comment: Out of my curiosity, any idea for the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519880/highlight-clicked-bar-series