# Highlight clicked bar series

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

Is there any built in method in kendo when user clicks on the bar chart item, then it will highlight all corresponding items?

For example in the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/va5pu8tf/3/), there are five items. If I click `item1` in the `first bar (1970)`, it should highlight `item1` in `second bar (1975)`.

```
series: [{
   type: "column",
   field: "value",
   stack: true,
   name: "#= group.value #"
}],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `seriesClick` event. Then determine which series was clicked and use the `toggleHighlight()` method to turn off highlighting on all other series and turn it on for the clicked one:

```
seriesClick: function(e) {
    var clickedSeries = e.series.name;
    var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
    for (var i=0; i< chart.options.series.length; i++){
        chart.toggleHighlight(false, chart.options.series[i].name);
    }
    chart.toggleHighlight(true, clickedSeries);
}
```

### Updated [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/va5pu8tf/8/)

Comment: I could not able to find a way to highlight border or paired objects on bar stack. Do you have any idea for the following question which is related this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632657/more-pronounce-highlight-effect