# Series Hover to Highlight Border Color

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following implementation which actually highlight paired objects on the  stacked bar chart.

However, I would like to know whether or not there is a way to implement more pronounced highlight effect. For example make bar paired bar stacks border black when hover the mouse.

```
seriesHover: function (e) {
   var clickedSeries = e.series.name;
   var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
   for (var i = 0; i < chart.options.series.length; i++) {
        chart.toggleHighlight(false, chart.options.series[i].name);
     }
   chart.toggleHighlight(true, clickedSeries);
}
```

**Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nss8d5kn/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default highlight has fill and stroke of white with opacity = 0.2. Therefore you can find paths with this stroke opacity and change them to black:

```
   $("#chart g path").each(function (idx){
        var op = $(this).attr('stroke-opacity');
        if (op == 0.2){
            $(this)
                .attr('stroke', '#000')
                .attr('stroke-opacity', 1)
                .attr('stroke-width', 2);
        }
    });
```

### Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/nss8d5kn/3/)**

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution, I could able to see highlighted border color, but it affects all of the item, I only want to be effective paired objects. http://jsfiddle.net/s8mywm33/19/

Comment: In other words, I only want to increase opacity and include stroke-width for paired objects

Comment: @mystackoverflow, When I run the fiddle in my answer, only the pairs are visible with the black border. Even though all borders are changed, only 2 are visible at a time.  Is that not what you are seeing?

Comment: I have paired them in the following fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/s8mywm33/20/ , but it is not working.

Comment: @mystackoverflow, that's because chart.toggleHighlight() works with series name (item1, item2, etc). So you would need items with the same fname to also have the same series name, or a way to know which series are paired and then toggleHighlight on both series.

Comment: how could I able to use `fname` for `series hover` event, because `fname` is the unique name/ keyword that identifies the each object, not `series`? Is there a way around to make it work?

Comment: @mystackoverflow could you make the series names be the fname? or have series names with the same fname be the same? If not could you setup a global variable that maps fnames to series names so that you can toggleHighlight on all series names that have the same fname...

Comment: I understand, however `series name` is used to follow object orders. If I assign the `series name` to the `fname`, then how could I follow object order?  That is my concern.

Comment: @mystackoverflow, here is your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/s8mywm33/21/  I have manually setup a mapping of fname to series names that have this fname. You could create this object in code as you iterate the data...

Comment: Thanks a lot Ezanker, appreciate your help! I have marked as an answer, already upvoted.

Comment: any idea for the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653450/multiple-tooltips-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve a naïve solution via pure CSS: [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kcbvtutu/).

```
g[clip-path] path + path {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
    stroke-width: 1;
}
```

However, since you can't change stacking order in SVG, some borders will be hidden under other elements. You may be able to solve that with some additional spacing.

Comment: But if you check the following link from Kendo-Chart, it shows there is an option to use highlight border color, Why I cannot use built-in feature from Kendo directly? If yes, how it will come to the picture of my current implementation. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.highlight.border.color  I have upvoted your initial effort.

Comment: From the docs: 'The border option is supported when series.type is set to "donut", "bubble", "pie", "candlestick" or "ohlc".' Not sure why this is the case, unfortunately.

Comment: Other options that you could recommend to pronounce highlight effect, it is not limited to border color.