# Is it possible to show multiple tooltips at the same time?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following implementation. It works and functional. When user hovers the mouse on the bar chart and if there are common/paired objects, the corresponding objects' bar border color are highlighted.

However, I would like to know whether or not there is a way to show tooltip at the same time across the paired objects. i.e multiple tooltips at the same time for paired objects.

```
seriesHover: function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    var fname = e.dataItem.fname;
    var ser = fnameMap[fname];
    var clickedSeries = e.series.name;
    var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.options.series.length; i++) {
        chart.toggleHighlight(false, chart.options.series[i].name);
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < ser.length; i++) {
        chart.toggleHighlight(true, ser[i]);
    }
     $("#chart g path").each(function (idx){
     var op = $(this).attr('stroke-opacity');
     if (op == 0.2){
       $(this)
        .attr('stroke', '#000')
        .attr('stroke-opacity', 1)
        .attr('stroke-width', 2);
   }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/s8mywm33/21/)

Comment: You could implement your own tooltip that shows all values with the same fname: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/s8mywm33/23/

Comment: Thanks a lot ezanker, however, when user hover the mouse, then how could I show tooltips of common objects at the same time., more than one tooltip at the same time.

Comment: @Ezanker, do you have any knowledge of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656016/legend-and-bar-chart-colors-do-not-match

Comment: look at my fiddle, the single tooltip shows values for all common objects...

Comment: Yes, it is showing, but I would like to know is there a way to open multiple tooltips at the same time? If you put your current answer, I would like to upvote by the way