# Legend and Bar Chart Colors do not match

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following implementation and I used colorField to assign colors. However, even though I color the bar stack objects properly, but this color does not match with legend color. I thought it should be bound somehow, how should I fix it?

I have used `colorField` because I want to assign the same color for paired objects in the bar stack column.

dataSample:

```
data[0] = {
    "value": 29,
    "series": 1,
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "NY",
    "valueColor": "black"
},
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/fm79hsms/13/

Comment: I found an article at http://www.telerik.com/forums/stack-bar-chart-legend-color-issue which may help you.

Comment: Is there a way to work around to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution, although it feels kind of hacky.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ost124j/)

I used legend.item.visual to redraw the legend and pulled in the valueColor from the data, which was nicely passed along to the legened.item.visual function.

```
legend: {
        item: {
            visual: function (e) {

                var color = ""

                for (var i=0;i<e.series.data.length;i++){
                    if (e.series.data[i].valueColor != "" && e.series.data[i].fname != "") {
                    color = e.series.data[i].valueColor
                    }
                }

              var rect = new kendo.geometry.Rect([0, 0], [100, 50]);
              var layout = new kendo.drawing.Layout(rect, {
                spacing: 5,
                alignItems: "center"
              });

              var marker = new kendo.drawing.Path({
                fill: {
                  color: color
                }
              }).moveTo(10, 0).lineTo(10, 10).lineTo(0, 10).lineTo(0,0).close();

              var label = new kendo.drawing.Text(e.series.name, [0, 0], {
                fill: {
                  color: "black"
                }
              });

              layout.append(marker, label);
              layout.reflow()

              return layout;
            }
         }
     },
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `this -> seriesColors: ["red", "green"]`, and configure your own color in kendo chart javascript.

Comment: The colorField is dynamic from the data, creating the seriesColors manually in JavaScript does not address the question asked. JFlox although hackish is the recommended way from Kendo.